# Making sense of Euclidean Algorithm Proof

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation

Hi I need help understanding this proof for the Euclidean algorithm. Specifically I do not understand what long inequality on the bottom means. Does k refer to an iteration?

[image]

Comment: What are the $r_i$ supposed to be in relation to the Euclidean algorithm? Remainders?

Comment: If gcd(2024,748) then ri = 748 . Not the remainder, but the divisor.

Comment: it assures the algorithm is over in k steps